# Change how many 'recent' files are shown in Preview's "Open Recent..." menu

Tags: preview, settings, menu-bar

I cannot find anything in the preferences to do this, but I would like to be able to lengthen the list that Preview offers in the "Open Recent" menu. Right now it displays the 9 most recent files. I would like it to show at least 20 or so. Is there some secret way to hack this from the command line, or is there a setting somewhere that  I just haven't been able to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the option at the bottom of **System Preferences > General**:[image]

Answer (score -1):

Go to System Preferences, then general. 3rd option up you can choose "Recent items", it goes up to 50.